# Angular Date type

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

From my angular interface date value coming like this.

```
Sat Dec 29 2018 08:42:06 GMT+0400 (Gulf Standard Time)
```

but after receiving data from api JSON result look like this. how to make it same type?

```
 2018-12-27T13:37:00.83
```

Typescript

```
export interface header{
    vr_date : Date  
}
```

Asp API class

```
 public class header
 { 
      public Nullable<System.DateTime> vr_date { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: What is the datatype in DB? Is it datetime?

Comment: database field is datetime

Comment: Ok, refer posted answer!

Comment: doesnt work same result. this.header.vr_date.getFullYear().toString().substring(2,4) gives error

Comment: Is that in C#..?

Comment: how do you want in C#? use the same variable without convert()

Comment: no from  angular  i get error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Angular's inbuilt [`DatePipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe). So all you need to do is:

In Component TS:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
 // other stuff
  providers:[DatePipe]
})

constructor(public datePipe : DatePipe){

}
```

To use it:

```
var format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"; // this could be `yyyy-MM-dd` or `MM/dd/yyyy`
this.datePipe.transform(your_date_variable, format);
```

EDIT:

If you want to convert a date into a GMT then use `your_date.toUTCString()`

then use:

```
var isoDate = new Date('2018-12-27T13:37:00.83');
var UTCDate = isoDate.toUTCString();
```

Which returns:

```
Thu, 27 Dec 2018 08:07:00 GMT
```

[`WORKING DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-klmtqx-yymxds)