# how can I use datePipe in my component using angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date-pipe

Is there a way I can use the DatePipe in my angular component?

this is my code.

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.days.length; i++) {
      this.storeStart(this.days[i], null, null, null);
    }
```

Every weekday (monday to friday) is stored inside my days array. I want to store this with the other data inside of another array. Now I get this: 'Fri Nov 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100'. But I only want it to display this: '01-11' (day-month). It's also being stored as a Date but I want to store this as a string. Can anyone help me out a bit?

Comment: Check this:https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular Date type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53966873/angular-date-type)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular - Use pipes in services and components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144821/angular-use-pipes-in-services-and-components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this by using a DI(dependency injection)

**TS**

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.days.length; i++) {
      let myDate = new DatePipe().transform(this.days[i], 'yyyy-MM-dd');
      this.storeStart(myDate, null, null, null);
}
```